# Symfony2. Doctrine. GeneratedValue for multi fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Symfony2 entity with fields:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="public_id", type="guid")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $publicId;
```

When I create an entity I have same error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO my_entity (id,
>   public_id, status, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   ["127c2df7-642d-494a-b2ee-4785fc4ecdaf", null, 3, "2015-03-11
>   01:29:02"]:     SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:
>   invalid input syntax for integer:
>   "127c2df7-642d-494a-b2ee-4785fc4ecdaf"

Where I made mistakes?

My goal is to make 2 IDs for internal and external uses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two Generated Values in Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915944/two-generated-values-in-doctrine)

Comment: What's the best practice for my issue?

Comment: now I use LifecycleCallbacks with Rhumsaa\Uuid lib

Comment: If you are just using a uuid then why not just generate it in the `__construct` rather than a lifecyclecallback? Doctrine will load that from reflection in future so it won't get overwritten and you don't have to rely on extra callbacks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?