# Symfony unique integer fields in entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, unique-constraint

I have entity with uniq field, `inviteCode`. And when I create new entity I want set automatic some random code, but this code must be different from exist in db, what do you thing, what practices about that you know ?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @AssertBridge\UniqueEntity(
 *     groups={"registration"},
 *     fields="inviteCode",
  *     errorPath="not valid",
 *     message="This inviteCode is already in use."
 * )
 */
 class User extends AbstractUser implements UserInterface
 {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, unique=true)
 * @Annotation\SerializedName("_invite_code")
 */
private $inviteCode;
```

I found something like that

```
    private function calculateReference($number)
{
    $multipliers = array(7,3,1);
    $length = strlen($number);
    $numberArr = str_split($number);

    $sum = 0;

    for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i)
    {
        $sum += $numberArr[$i] * $multipliers[($length - 1 - $i) % 3];
    }

    return $number.(10 - $sum % 10) % 10;
}
```

first get max id from table then call function `calculateReference` with id and then `setInviteCode`.

But I believe doctrine have something exist for this issue or maybe somebody have good example for this

Comment: In which way will you use your inviteCode ? Please give us some context of the needed feature to drive you to the best solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone provided a great answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13917309/4173130.

But like he said at the end, you don't need doctrine for such a simple feature. Generating the code in the constructor is an efficient, simple and clear solution.

You can use a UUID library like [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid). Then you would be able to generate any random code with `Uuid::uuid4();`.

Another solution is to use [random_bytes()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.random-bytes.php) with `base64_encode` : `base64_encode(random_bytes(32))`.

Please don't try to create a new function to generate random values. Most of time  it is not secure, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insecure_Randomness.

Comment: What about uniq data from `ramsey/uuid` ? After generate data by `uuid` need to check `inviteCode` in data base ? And how get and set data, like this `$uuid = Uuid::uuid4(); $user->setInviteCode($uuid->jsonSerialize());` ?

Comment: Like I said, just generate the code in the constructor. Then you can use a Doctrine Type or a string to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a uuid? It is included in php as a core function and i believe it suits your needs.

Check in the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)